# Nginx server block doesn't work. really simple case.

Tags: nginx

I have this block in my config file:

```
   server {
     listen 80;
    server_name test;
    root d:/pathto/test/;
  }
```

In my localhosts file I set he DNS for test to be 127.0.0.1. That works. The Nginx home page is displayed. (So the localhosts file part of it works). But the 'virtual host' is not working. I stil get the main 'virtual host' - the default Nginx page. I've tried the simplest case I can. I can't see the problem. What could be the problem?

This is on Windows 8.

Thanks

--Justin Wyllie

Comment: I'm not sure if this is correct, but I think windows use backslashes not forward slashes, try `d:\path\to\test;`

Answer (score 0):

What dou you call "virtual host? Add locations for your subfolders:

```
http{
      server {
         listen 80;
        server_name test;
        root d:/pathto/test/;
        location / {
           index index.php index.htm index.html;
        }
      }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Still not working. I've added an error_log. the log is created but nothing in it. (I'm just calling it virtual host to explain more what I am trying to do. I know it is not the same thing). Thanks

Comment: You just put an index.html to d:/pathto/test/ and type [http://test](http://test) in your browser, am I right? And a stupid question did you enable your site? or you put your config to nginx.conf? And another one question does the path to the root folder contains spaces?

Comment: Yes. you're right. Enable my site? That sounds interesting. How do I do this on Windows 8? My nginx.conf seems fine and is being used. And, no no spaces - but it is on a drive other than the main one: d:/pathto/test;

Comment: Resolved. Not 100% sure why but I think I had multiple workers running and my new config file changes were only being taken by one worker. A computer restart cleared it.

Comment: Yes. Thanks. I'm looking forward to really getting into Nginx. I have a 'virtual private server' with memory issues.